# I want to reinstall my Windows 7 but will my Ubuntu be uninstalled with it?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu

I installed the Ubuntu 11.04 inside of Win 7 via Wubi. It works great and I don't want to reinstall it again, now I want to reinstall my Win 7, is there a way to keep Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Wubi installs Ubuntu as though its a Windows Application. So reinstalling Win 7 will require you to  reinstall Ubuntu. Although you can make a backup of Ubuntu and restore it later.....
Relevant [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1422572)